# How to import tensorflow coco-ssd model in Nodejs electron application

Tags: node.js, tensorflow, electron

Facing problem while importing tensorflow model and using already trained coco-ssd model. Problem I faced is on electron application in Nodejs .

Successfully running coco-ssd mode example code provided on github: using yarn but my application is electron based. I am getting real time images from camera and saving them in my dataset.

```
var cocoSsd= require('@tensorflow-models/coco-ssd');
console.log(cocoSsd);

const img = document.getElementById('img');

// Load the model.
const model = await cocoSsd.load();

// Classify the image.
const predictions = await model.detect(img);

console.log('Predictions: ');
console.log(predictions);

code = "(function (exports, require, module, __filename, _".....
```

I am not willing to use: `import * as cocoSsd from '@tensorflow-models/coco-ssd';`

[image: Run time error message]